# Array of strings and layouting in a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, regex, arrays, string, uilabel

I've been trying to wrap my head around a relatively simple problem, but doing for loops and a ton of comparing is really making my head spin.

Here's the problem:
Let's say I have an array of strings. Each string is a single word, parsed from one or several sentences. Ideally, I'd want to create a new array that joins these single strings into multi-word strings based on two facts: words per line and the number of lines.

As an example, let's say that I have 4 words and I set the words per line to 2, as well as the number of lines to 2, then it would display them like this:

*Word1 Word2*

*Word3 Word4*

Granted there are special cases where there are only 3 words, which would divide the first 2 words on the first line and the last 1 on the second line.

How would you guys approach this type of problem, surely there's a simpler way of doing this, rather than only using mind numbing nested loops and if/else sentences?

Comment: Why would you need to nest loops? Couldn't you use one loop? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, why not use a multi-line label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will output a `NSMutableArray` of arrays each of which contains the number of strings you provided. So if number of strings is 3 then each array will have 3 strings, unless theres no strings left, in which case it will add as many as it can.

```
int numLines = 4;
int numWordsPerLine = 3;

NSArray *strings = @[@"String1", @"String2", @"String3", @"String4", @"String5", @"String6", @"String7", @"String8"];

NSMutableArray *matrixArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numLines];

NSEnumerator *enuma = [strings objectEnumerator];

int linesCount = 0;
while (linesCount < numLines) {
    [matrixArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    for (int i = 0; i < numWordsPerLine; i++) {
        id nextObject = [enuma nextObject];
        if (nextObject) {
            [[matrixArray objectAtIndex:linesCount] addObject:nextObject];
        }
    }
    linesCount++;
}
NSLog(@"Matrix %@", matrixArray);
```

That would output:

```
2013-11-12 11:42:06.940 WordPuzzle[1900:a0b] Matrix (
        (
        String1,
        String2,
        String3
    ),
        (
        String4,
        String5,
        String6
    ),
        (
        String7,
        String8
    ),
        (
    )
)
```

If you change `numLines` to 2 and then `numWordsPerLine` to 4 you would then get:

```
2013-11-12 11:43:39.014 WordPuzzle[1936:a0b] Matrix (
        (
        String1,
        String2,
        String3,
        String4
    ),
        (
        String5,
        String6,
        String7,
        String8
    )
)
```